# Angular2 Component not initializing after login

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, ecmascript-6, components

I setup authentication in my angular2 app, which is based on the [Angular2 Webpack Starter repo](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter).

Protected routes and login works perfectly, but the problem is that after login, the component does not initialize itself. It just loads the component but all the the Angular2 bindings like `{{ somevar }}` don't load, UNTIL I click on a form or click the component navigation route again. Then it initializes.

What could be causing the components to fail to load after login?

Here is my app:
http://starterhome.azurewebsites.net

Comment: Looks like some code doesn't run inside Angulars zone. You can inject `zone:NgZone` and then `zone.run(() => { codeRunsInsideAngularsZoneAgain(); });`

Comment: I have the same problem and it's driving me mad. It happens only after auto-login. When user is logged manually, everything is initialized just fine. @TetraDev , could you check how you did it?